# mvn/m2e don't doesn't take M1 M2

Tags: java, maven, m2e

The downloaded application I'm working on has an unversioned dependency.
Seems like it (`spring-boot-devtools`) has only x.y.z-M1<->M4 packages and neither `mvn` nor `m2e` wants to proceed with it when declared as:

```
<version>1.3.0-M4</version>
```

The error is:

> Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.3.0.M1 in central (repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

What am I missing there? Should I manually download & place it at the right location?

Comment: _And neither mvn or m2e wants to proceed with it when declared as:_ please elaborate it

Comment: $ mvn -U -up compile

.....

Could not find artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:jar:1.3.0.M1 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Comment: Thanks, Tunaki has posted solution already

Comment: @CaptainBlood I added the error message to your post so that it is clearer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

Spring milestone releases are not available on Maven Central. They are only available on Spring milestone repository ([documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#overview-maven-dependency-management)).

Therefore, you need to add the following repository to your `pom.xml`:

```
<repository>
    <id>spring-milestone</id>
    <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
</repository>
```